# Streaming into BQ partitioned tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to use dataflow to stream into BQ partitioned table. 
The documentation says that:

> Data in the streaming buffer has a NULL value for the _PARTITIONTIME column.

I can see that's the case when inserting rows into a date partitioned table.

Is there a way to be able to set the partition time of the rows I want to insert so that BigQuery can infer the correct partition?

So far I've tried doing: `tableRow.set("_PARTITIONTIME", milliessinceepoch);` 
but I get hit with a `no such field` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of a month or so ago, you can stream into a specific partition of a date-partitioned table. For example, to insert into partition for date 20160501 in table T, you can call insertall with table name `T$20160501`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, as of writing, BigQuery does not allow specifying the partition manually per row - it is inferred from the time of insertion.

However, as an alternative to BigQuery's built-in partitioned tables feature, you can use Dataflow's feature for streaming to multiple BigQuery tables at the same time: see [Sharding BigQuery output tables](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO#sharding-bigquery-output-tables).